# Light Weight C HTTP Client for Windows

Tags: c, http, post, get, httpclient

I'm sort of new to C language. I came from higher level languages like python and C#. I need to write a small light weight HTTP client for windows which has two features: the first it's that it could eventually perform GET requests, read the content of the page (excluding the headers) and print the results.The second one is to POST the time of the current machine to the server.

In my journey to complete this, I got really confused and currently I have really no idea how to do that.

I'd appreciate your help :)
Thanks !

Comment: 1. Do you know anything about sockets? 2. Why don't you use a known library like [`libcurl`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)?

Comment: I know sockets from higher level languages. I tried libcurl I just got really confused. A little code snippet would be appriciated!

Comment: I am sorry @FernandoRetimo, this is not the place for that, but the link I gave you has a lot of examples, and sending get/post requests is very easy using libcurl no matter what programming language. Although I could do it if you can pay me.

Comment: Also why is it a requirement that you do it on Windows? is it that you want to, or was it required from you?

Comment: iharob - The requirement for windows it's because I saw on many places using the library uni* which are for UNIX Systems so I though I had to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html), it is a nice guide for beginners in socket programming in C. If you are not a beginner you can just jump to the Client-Server section. There you can find examples on how to build clients and servers in C.

Comment: I wonder iharob why the downvote, this guide really helped me begin socket programming in C, so why spend 125 rep to downvote this?

Comment: Fernando this guide works on any platform using gcc, so it should work for you.